# Prevent Gunicorn 30 seconds timeout using AJAX on Django

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.x, gunicorn

I configured my Django app with Gunicorn (in a virtual env) and Lighttpd.
When I process a lot of data, a 500 error occurs. It is due to a default Gunicorn timeout set to 30 seconds.
I tried to use AJAX thinking of solving this issue but the only (wrong) way I found to solve the issue is to add a --timeout of 300 seconds in my costom systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=django daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/root/startDjango.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

with startDjango.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/django_apps/venv36/bin/gunicorn --log-file=/opt/django_apps/mydjangoapp/logs/gunicorn.log --bind XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY --chdir /opt/django_apps/mydjangoapp mydjangoapp.wsgi --timeout 300
```

Is there a way to solve this issue without increasing gunicorn timeout?

Comment: what do you mean it's wrong way? Gunicorn by default kills a process and restarts it after it has been hanging for more than 30 seconds. You set it to 300 by your requirement because your process takes so long. What's the problem now?

Comment: The problem is I cannot predict how long it will take for each process. If a process takes more than 5 minutes in this case I will have the same problem

Comment: then set it to 0 if that's some test environment you are playing with. In production though, you have to move all the heavy calculations to background tasks and only respond with results and statuses for API calls, like 'not ready yet'; (after 5 minutes) 'results ready!' results:[{..}{..}]

Comment: It's a small intranet application, not such a production env. Can you link me a tutorial to know how to manage bit calculations with bakground task?

Comment: google one of these: Celery, Dramatiq, Huey. Choose whichever you are more comfortable with